# Make time interval calculation in -[SKScene update:] account for "paused" status

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, sprite-kit

When I pause the game and wait some time, then resume the game, an alien ship is immediately added. How do I make it so that the 'timer' doesn't continue once the game is paused?

My Code:

```
@implementation GamePlayScene
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
               ...
    self.addAlienTimeInterval = [Util randomWithMin:10 max:25];
    self.timeSinceLastAlien = 0;
               ...
}

-(void) update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime{
    if (!_isGamePaused){
        if (self.lastUpdateTimeInterval){
            self.timeSinceLastAlien += currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
        }
        if (self.timeSinceLastAlien > self.addAlienTimeInterval && !self.gameOver){
            [self addAlienShip];
            self.timeSinceLastAlien = 0;
        }
        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
                ...
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update:` process isn't assigning `lastUpdateTimeInterval` while the "paused" condition is true, so when you resume, `timeSinceLastAlien` is augmented based on the `lastUpdateTimeInterval` that was seen way back when you first hit the pause button.

You need to keep updating the `lastUpdateTimeInterval` property while `_isGamePaused` is true in order for the interval `currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval` to reflect un-paused game time.